# $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} {\frac{x^2y}{x+xy+y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I was playing around with limits of two real variables, when I came up with the one on the title.
I tried all directional limits and they were all $0.$
So then I tried a few relative limits like $y=ax^2$ , $y=x^3-x^2$ and $0\leq x=\sqrt{y}$, but still got $0.$
 I tried then with $y=\cos(x)-1,$ and it gave a complicated expression which I plugged into symbolab, and it gave $0$ too.

So I tried to prove that it exists and is $0.$ So I'd need to find an inequality between the expression below and a norm $ \vert \vert (x,y) \vert \vert.$ I don't see how to manipulate it however, since the things in the denominator can be negative, and the only inequality I know can be applied here is $|xy| \leq x^2+y^2$, which would get:

$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x+xy+y^2}\right| \leq \left| \frac{x^2+x^2y^2}{x+xy+y^2} \right|.$$

I don't know how to proceed from that, nor have any other ideas to try to disprove it exists.

If possible give just a hint please, and I haven't yet learned polar coordinates nor partial derivatives.

Comment: *Hint*: Try to find the "no-go path", where the denominator vanishes and the numerator doesn't.

Comment: @Luis I tried solving $x+xy+y^2=0$ for $y$ and tried to evaluate the limit with one of the resulting solutions. It was a big expression so I plugged it in a online limit solver, and for both solutions [I still got 0](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/limit-calculator/?f=%28x%5E2%28%28-x-+sqrt+%28x%5E2-4x%29%2F2%29%29%29%2F%28x%2Bx%28-x-+sqrt+%28x%5E2-4x%29%2F2%29%2B%28-x-+sqrt+%28x%5E2-4x%29%2F2%29%5E2%29&var=x&val=0&dir=-&steps=on).

Comment: You have two variables. If solving for one makes it harder...

Answer (score 1):

The key issue here is to find a meaningful lower bound on $|x + xy + y^2|$; this can be written as

$$|x + xy + y^2| = |xy| \left|\frac{1}{y} + 1 + \frac y x\right|.$$

This is problematic if

$$\frac 1 y + \frac y x \approx -1$$

So try thinking about a case where $y \to 0^+$ (in which case the first term blows up), but where $x \to 0^-$ is carefully balanced with $y$ to cause a problem.

---

> This is the case on a [hyperbola](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fy+%2B+y%2Fx+%3D+-1) and is quite apparent from a plot of the [surface](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+y+%2F+(x+%2B+xy+%2B+y%5E2)+from+-1+to+1).

Comment: Hmm I tried $y= \sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}$ but still got 0.

Comment: My A is  just to flesh out the details of yours, and I only wrote it because of the proposer's comment to yours, indicating (s)he didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

For any open disc $D$ containing $(0,0)$  we can find $(x,y)\in D$ with $x\ne 0\ne y$ and $x+xy+y^2=0....$ I.e. if $y\ne 0$ and $ |y|$ is small enough and $  x=-y^2/(1+y).$

Then for any $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ we can also find $(x_n,y_n)\in D,$ close enough to $(x,y)$ that  $|x^2y-x_n^2y_n|<|x^2y|/2$ (which implies $|x_n^2y_n|>|x^2y|/2$)..... and also such that $0<|x_n+x_ny_n+y_n^2|<1/n .$

That is so, because the functions $a(u,v)=u^2v$ and $b(u,v)=u+uv+v^2$ are continuous, and $b(u,v)$ is not constantly $0$ on any non-empty open disc.

Let $g(u,v)=\frac {u^2v}{u+uv+v^2}$ when $u+uv+v^2\ne 0.$ So $|g( x_n,y_n)|>\frac {|x^2y|/2}{1/n}=n|x^2y|/2.$

So $\{|g(u,v)|:(u,v)\in D \land u+uv+v^2\ne 0\}\supset \{|g(x_n,y_n)|:n\in \Bbb Z^+\},$ which is a set with no upper bound.

So even when we exclude all $(x,y)$ such that $x+xy+y^2=0,$ the limit in question still does not exist.

Footnote: Regarding the first line above, if $r>0$ and $D=\{(u,v):u^2+v^2<r^2\},$ let $0<y<\min (1/2, r/2)$ and $x=-y^2/(1+y).$ Then $|x|<y^2$ so $x^2<y^4<y^2/4 $ so $x^2+y^2<y^2/4+y^2=5y^2/4<r^2.$

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding where those $x_n$ and $y_n$ sequences came from, can you please clarify?

Comment: Suppose $D=\{(u,v):u^2+v^2<r^2\}$ and $x^2+y^2=s^2<r^2.$  Let $(v_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ converge to $y,$ with each $y_j\ne -1.$ Let $u_j=1/j-y^2/(1+y).$ So $((u_j,v_j))_{j\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $(x,y).$ Now take any $n\in \Bbb N.$ The function $c(u,v)=u^2+v^2$ and the functions $a,b $ are continuous, so each of the sets $A_n= \{j\in \Bbb N: |a(u_j,v_j)-a(z,y)\ge |xy^2|/2\},\; B_n=\{j\in \Bbb N:|b(u_j,v_j)-b(x,y)|\ge  1/n\},\;$ $ C_n=\{j\in \Bbb N:|c(u_j,v_j)-c(x,y)|\ge r^2-s^2\}$ are finite. So take some $j(n)\in \Bbb N\setminus (A_n\cup B_n\cup C_n).$ Now let  $(x_n,y_n)=(u_{j(n)},v_{j(n)}).$

Comment: I can understand that there's a sucession $(x_n , y_n ) \in D$ such that $|x_n^2 y_n | \gt |x^2y|/2$ and that there's a sucession such that $0 \lt |x_ n +x_n y_n + y_n^2 | \lt \frac{1}{n}$ . However it is not obvious to me that there is a sucession that satisfies both conditions at same time, could you explain how you know that?

(sorry for late question, this is a bit complicated to me at moment so I keep rereading this periodically to try to understand it).

Comment: I have made a small edit: The function $b(u,v)$ is not constantly $0$ on any  open disc. Let $E$ be an open disc centered at $(x,y)$ with $E\subset D,$ and such that $(u,v)\in E\implies |a(u,v)-a(x,y)|<|x^2y/2.$  Let $F_n$ be an open disc centered at $(x,y)$ with $F_n\subset D$ and such that $(u,v)\in F_n\implies 1/n>|b(u,v)-b(x,y)|=|b(,u,v)|.$ Then $G_n=E\cap F_n$ is either $E$ or $F_n,$ and $(u,v)\in G_n\implies (|a(u,v)|>|x^2y|/2\land |b(u,v)|<1/n).$ And $b$ is not constantly $0$ on $G_n$ so there exists $(x_n,y_n)\in G$ with $b(x_n,y_n)\ne 0.$

Comment: Look at it geometrically. Consider the graph $H(r)=\{(f(y),y): y\in (0,r)\}$ for any $r\in (0,1/2).$  For any $(f(y),y)\in H(r),$ restrict $u$ to values in $(f(y),0).$ Then $\lim_{u\to f(y)} a(u,y)=a(f(y),y)\ne 0.$ But $b(u,y)\ne 0$ and $\lim_{u\to 0}b(u,y)=b(f(y),y)=0.$  So $\{g(u,y): u\in (f(y),0)\}$ is an unbounded set. BTW this also shows that in my A we can always have $y_n=y$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complet answer, but is valid if $x,y>0.$

From $$0<x^2y<x^2y+x^2y^2+xy^3$$ we deduce
$$0<{\frac{x^2y}{x+xy+y^2}}<{\frac{x^2y+x^2y^2+xy^3}{x+xy+y^2}}=xy,$$and with the use of squeeze theorem $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^{+},0^{+})} {\frac{x^2y}{x+xy+y^2}}=0.$$