# Proof $|a-b| \lt \frac{|a|}{2} \rightarrow |b| \gt \frac{|a|}{2}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, inequality

> In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3129803/647185) to a question of mine, in the second paragraph, the author uses an expression analogous to $|a-b| \lt \frac{|a|}{2}$ , and then in the parenteses says that it implies that $|b| \gt \frac{|a|}{2}$.

It didn't seem obvious to me so I tried to prove it:

I assumed $|a-b| \lt \frac{|a|}{2}$, which is equivalent to $-\frac{|a|}{2} \lt a-b \lt \frac{|a|}{2}$. Adding b to both sides gets

$$ b-\frac{|a|}{2} \lt a \lt b+ \frac{|a|}{2}$$

Noting that $b \leq |b|$ and $-|b| \leq b$ we obtain

$$-|b| - \frac{|a|}{2} \lt a \lt |b| + \frac{|a|}{2}$$

$$\iff |a| \lt |b| + \frac{|a|}{2} \iff |b| \gt \frac{|a|}{2}. \square $$

This was not too easy for me so my questions are:

$\bullet$ Is this proof correct?

$\bullet$ Is there an easier way to prove this?

$\bullet$ How is a more experienced mathematician able to deal with these inequalities so easily, that (s)he doesn't need to write them down when using them in a proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

You can also use triangle inequality: 
$$|a| \le |a-b|+|b| < \frac{|a|}{2}+|b| \implies \frac{|a|}{2} < |b|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $|x|^2 = x^2$. If you square it you get $$4(a-b)^2< a^2$$ so $$(2a-2b-a)(2a-2b+a)<0$$
or
$$(a-2b)(3a-2b)<0$$

solving this quadratic inequality on $b$ we conclude that $$\boxed{\color{red}{{a\over 2}<b<{3a\over 2}}}$$

Comment: Imho OP's proof is much simpler than this.

Comment: @user159517 Why? We get even more info about the $b$.

Comment: @MariaMazur Your answer is not complete. You are not given whether $a$ and/or $b$ are positive and/or negative. Your conclusion is just for $a - 2b \lt 0$ and $3a - 2b \gt 0$. Considering $a - 2b \gt 0$ and $3a - 2b \lt 0$ gives $\frac{a}{2} \gt b \gt \frac{3a}{2}$, which is possible if $a$ and $b$ are negative. Thus, overall, you can reasonably state that $\left|\frac{a}{2}\right| \lt \left|b\right| \lt \left|\frac{3a}{2}\right|$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Are you sure about that?

Comment: @MariaMazur Sorry, I got my inequalities mixed around, but I believe it's correct now. Please check this yourself. To see why the extra condition is necessary, consider $a = -1$ and $b = -1$. As such, $\mid a - b \mid = 0$, which is less than $\frac{\mid a \mid}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$. However, your statement gives that $-\frac{1}{2} \lt -1 \lt -\frac{3}{2}$ which, of course, is not true.

Comment: @JohnOmielan No, I'm not saying that, I say $b$ is between $a/2$ and $3a/2$ and not that $-1$ is between $-1/2$ and $-3/2$.

Comment: @MariaMazur Your statement is specifically that $\frac{a}{2} \lt b$ and $b \lt \frac{3a}{2}$. However, if $a = b = -1$, the original inequality is satisfied, as I state, but neither of yours is since $\frac{-1}{2}$ is **not** less than $-1$ and $-1$ is **not** less than $\frac{-3}{2}$. The correct general statement is that $\mid b \mid$ is between $\mid \frac{a}{2} \mid$ and $\mid \frac{3a}{2} \mid$, which matches yours if $a$ is positive, but not if $a$ is negative.

Comment: You mean if I wrote $x<y$ than you claim this is wrong since 2<1 is not valid? @JohnOmielan

Comment: Your answer is not wrong or not valid, it's just **not** complete. The OP is trying to show that one inequality implies another. To prove this, you need to show that **all** valid values which hold in the first inequality also hold in the second. You have only considered a specific subset, stating just one set of conditions which doesn't allow various other vallid sets of values, like the $a = b = -1$ that I suggest. However, they also need to be considered for a complete, correct answer.

Comment: @MariaMazur To put it another way, if you're asked to categorize all values of $c$ and $d$ for which $cd \lt 0$, you can't limit the answer to just $c \lt 0$ and $d \gt 0$, which is essentially what you've done. Instead, you need to say that $c \lt 0$ and $d \gt 0$, **or**, $c \gt 0$ and $d \lt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

When I read your hypothesis, $|a-b| \lt \frac{|a|}{2}$, this is what I mentally translated it into:  The distance from $a$ to $b$ is less than half the distance from $a$ to $0$.  I concluded that $b$ must be closer to $a$ than to $0$; that is, $b$ is further from $0$ (in the direction toward $a$) than the halfway point $\frac{a}{2}$ is.  In symbols, that becomes $|b| \gt |\frac{a}{2}|$.